# Not able to install PySide

Tags: python, pip, pyside

```
C:\Users\Anas>pip install -U PySide
Collecting PySide
  Using cached PySide-1.2.4.tar.gz (9.3 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      only these python versions are supported: [(2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

C:\Users\Anas>

C:\Users\Anas>python --version
Python 3.10.10

C:\Users\Anas>pip --version
pip 23.0.1 from C:\Users\Anas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)
```

I am following a tutorial to learn Python but I am stuck at installing PySide.
Its not installing in my machine can anybody please help me.

I tried to installed python 2.7 and Python 3.4 as well.
From this website.
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-340/

Can anybody please help me install PySide?

Comment: The package "PySide" in pip has not been updated since 2015 and is for old versions of Qt. You probably want "PySide2" (if using Qt 5) or "PySide6" (if using Qt 6).

Answer (score 1):

`PySide` with `Qt4` supports versions of python `>=2.6` and `<=3.4`. `PySide2` with `Qt5` supports versions of python `>3.4` and `<3.11`. `PySide6` with `Qt6` supports version of python `>=3.7` and `<3.12`. Depending on **your** version of `Qt` you're either going to have to upgrade it if it's `Qt4` because your version of python is `3.10.10`.

If you have `Qt5`:

```
pip install PySide2
```

If you have `Qt6`:

```
pip install PySide6
```